# Failed to run Laravel 5 project on browser

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel, I am using windows 7 OS. I have a PHP website made on laravel 5 which I want to run on my browser. I have gone through the videos and the various website on "How to run laravel 5 project on browser" but unfortunately I failed to run my project on the browser.
I am using XAMPP and below is my Virtual Hosts file of apache. My localhost port is 7000.

```
<VirtualHost *:7000>

    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp2\htdocs\basicwebsite\public"
    ServerName basicwebsite.com

</VirtualHost>
```

And inside the hosts file within the system32 folder I have put the following line

```
127.0.0.1   basicwebsite.com
```

When I am trying to run it on my browser it gives me an error

```
"This site can’t be reached
basciwebsite.com refused to connect."
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `localhost/basicwebsite/public`, is this working?

Comment: when I type http://localhost:7000/basicwebsite/public on my browser it gives me a red header page which says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: what url do you type in you browser, basicwebsite.com or basicwebsite.com:7000
?

Comment: Hi @Shantanu command fire php artisan server then check or refresh browser.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs I tried with both basicwebsite.com and  basicwebsite.com:7000  but none of them works, it gives me the same error This site can’t be reached

Comment: Did you restart your web server after making the config changes?

Answer (score 1):

When I'm developing locally with Laravel, I simply execute **php artisan serve** on the terminal. I can then run it on http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

check below points -

1.)  .env file should have APP_KEY
2.)  have you created "storage/views" , "storage/cache"

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<VirtualHost *:7000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
    ServerName basicwebsite.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp2/htdocs/basicwebsite">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work, same error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something other than basicwebsite.com in the servername, 
Maybe use basicwebsite.local

Explanation:
.com is widely used therefore using something different should do the trick, try http://nameofwebsite.local 
(doesn't have to be .local, can be anything really but not .com or .net for example)

Comment: Using .local, is taking me to google and it displays different websites.

Comment: I have edited my answer, just try adding http:// before the domain name. should get it working. let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried with .in that is I tried with http://nameofwebsite.in but now the error is http:// nameofwebsite.in’s server IP address could not be found.